# Attach xlsx file to email with MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating xlsx file and save it to directory.I wanted to email this excel file to user but keeps failing. searched online but couldn't find any working one. 
So far i did this but received file is  zero size.

```
        public void SendSingle2(string filePath)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", "test@gmail.com"));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("MnM", "test@hotmail.com"));
        emailMessage.Subject = "Report";

        var builder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = "Incident Report." };
        if (filePath != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                builder.Attachments.Add("Report.xlsx",memoryStream);
            }
        }

        emailMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();



        using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
        {

            emailClient.Connect(_emailConfiguration.SmtpServer, _emailConfiguration.SmtpPort, true);


            emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            emailClient.Authenticate(_emailConfiguration.SmtpUsername, _emailConfiguration.SmtpPassword);

            emailClient.Send(emailMessage);

            emailClient.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming that you confirmed the file on your filesystem is actually bigger than 0 bytes?

Comment: Yes. It is bigger than 0. Actually when I receive the email, attachment shows the correct file size but when I download the attachment from email it is zero

Answer (score 0):

In case sombody else, like me, stumbled upon this old unanswered StackOverflow question, the following code was tested and works:

Used MailKit 3.4.2

```
using MimeKit;
using System.IO;

public static void Send()
{
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Somebody", "somebody@domain.org"));
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("SomebodyElse", "somebody.else@domain.org"));
    message.Subject = "Email with Excel Attachment";

    // MultiPart Body
    var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
    multipart.Add(new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
    {
        Text = "Email message<br><br>kind regards, X"
    });

    // MultiPart Attachments - Create an attachment for the Excel file
    var excelFilename = @"c:\temp\ExcelFile.xlsx";
    var attachment = new MimePart("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    {
        Content = new MimeContent(File.Open(excelFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)),
        ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Binary,
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(excelFilename)
    };

    // Create the multipart/mixed container to hold the message text and the attachment
    multipart.Add(attachment);

    // Set multipart/mixed as the message body
    message.Body = multipart;

    var smtpServer = "***";
    var smtpPort = 123;
    var smtpUserName = "***";
    var smtpPassword = "***";
    using (var smtpClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true; // Disable SSL Verification
        smtpClient.Connect(smtpServer, smtpPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

        // Remove any OAuth functionality as we won't be using it. 
        //smtpClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

        smtpClient.Authenticate(smtpUserName, smtpPassword);
        var smtpResponse = smtpClient.Send(message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SMTP response=({smtpResponse})");
        smtpClient.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we do this from an excel file as Byte? I achieved to send the bytes as attachement, I see an .xlsx file, but when i want to open it, excel throw error saying the file is bad

Comment: The code below works for me, just replace the Content assignment with your stream:

 `using (var stream = File.OpenRead(excelFilename))
 {
  var attachment = new MimePart("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
  {
   Content = new MimeContent(stream),
   ...
  };
 }`